# 3 column circles and responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am curious if there are any tutorials or sample code for a layout that has 3 circles side by side with text underneath each. Also so that it is responsive so it only 1 circle with the text underneath then the next one and so on.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, if you're familiar with Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <span>This is a text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <span>This is a text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <span>This is a text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
      .circle{
       position: relative;
       border-radius: 50%;
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       padding-top: 100%;
       background: black;
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should have a look at the bootstrap library.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
      <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="yourcirclepicture.png" alt="circle">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            your text
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="yourcirclepicture.png" alt="circle">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            your text
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="yourcirclepicture.png" alt="circle">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            your text
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the class row identifies which content should be in one row if there is enogh space. if the window is smaller the content (each col-md-4) will be placed under each other.

dont forget to include the bootstrap library.

that sould be all.